# How to handle number and string types interchangibly when using input forms?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

My problem is that as far as I know javascript can't handle number format in forms and converts everything to string.

I have a function that lets users select their macronutrient ratio percentages - the sum of carbs, fats, protein have to be sum of 100%.

I store users goal macros as a **number** in my database and I calculate current percentage totals like this:

```
  const carbsPercentage = ((goalCarbs * 4) / goalCalories) * 100;
  const fatsPercentage = ((goalFats * 9) / goalCalories) * 100;
  const proteinPercentage = ((goalProtein * 4) / goalCalories) * 100;
```

Then using `React-hook-form` `watch()` method I track users form inputs to recalculate the total percentage:

```
  const watchCarbsPercentage = watch('carbsPercentage');
  const watchFatsPercentage = watch('fatsPercentage');
  const watchProteinPercentage = watch('proteinPercentage');
  const watchCalories = watch('calories');

  // gets total percentage based on the sum of the other 3
  const getTotalPercentage = () => {
    const parsedCarbsPercentage = parseInt(watchCarbsPercentage) || 0;
    const parsedFatsPercentage = parseInt(watchFatsPercentage) || 0;
    const parsedProteinPercentage = parseInt(watchProteinPercentage) || 0;
    const totalPercentage =
      parsedCarbsPercentage + parsedFatsPercentage + parsedProteinPercentage;
    return totalPercentage;
  };
```

Because of this I get typescript error when I try to use `parseInt`:

```
const watchCarbsPercentage: number
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I thought that typescript would infer that as soon as number is assigned to input it becomes string or am I wrong?

How do I handle this logic correctly?[image]

Comment: What does `watch()` do?

Comment: @Terry it tracks the current input value